# CloudKit access issues on save

Tags: cloudkit

I'm adding CloudKit to my app and I'm trying to save a record like so:

```swift
try await CKContainer.default().privateCloudDatabase.save(record)
```

When I run via Xcode on my personal iPhone, it comes back and says:

> CloudKit access was denied by user settings

I am not seeing how I request access from the user.

Comment: In your iCloud settings, is iCloud Drive turned on?

Comment: That was it, thanks!